# Selecting records after using insert cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-attribute, error-000358

Using ArcPy and on the same script, I would like to perform a SelectLayerByAttribute tool to select the features created with the InsertCursor tool.

```
coords = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pointlyr = 'point' 
Sr = arcpy.spatialReference(4326)
Points = [arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(coords[0], coords[1]), sr), arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(coords[2], coords[3]), sr)]

ids = []
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(pointlyr, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for pt in Points:
        cursor.insertRow([pt])
        id = max(set(str(for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointlyr, "OBJECTID")))
        ids.append(id)

query = f"OBJECTID IN {str(tuple(ids))}"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttributes(pointlyr, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

However, the attribute table does not refresh and it gives me an error message of invalid query. The SearchCursor tool allows me to query the newly created records programmatically however I want the records to be selected on the map extent and attribute table. How can I overcome this issue?

**Update**
Error message attached.
[image: Invalid expression error]

Comment: You can't use `with` with an old-style non-DA cursor, and can't read the contents until it is flushed.

Comment: Thank you, Vince. I've since edited the code on this page. The code works fine save for the last line with the SelectLayerByAttribute tool. The query is fine as I've tested it on existing records.

Comment: Try enclosing the tuple in () and not {} in the expression.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, the expression doesn't work with (). The expression works fine as I've tested it on another FC. I believe its because the records weren't refreshed on the layer yet and prevent the SelectLayerByAttribute tool from selecting it.

Answer (score 1):

The [InsertCursor - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) returns an object, specifically an integer representing the ObjectID of the record that was just inserted, so all you have to do is store those integers.

```py
coords = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pointlyr = 'point' 
Sr = arcpy.spatialReference(4326)
Points = [arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(coords[0], coords[1]), sr), arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(coords[2], coords[3]), sr)]

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(pointlyr, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    ids = [cursor.insertRow([pt]) for pt in Points]


query = f"OBJECTID IN ({','.join(str(id) for id in ids)})"
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('pointlyr', "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

As convenient as `str(tuple(ids))` is, it will generate invalid SQL if there is only a single item in the list, so you should go with something different like `','.join(str(id) for id in ids)`.

Also, the tool is `SelectLayerByAttribute`, no 's', and it resides in the `arcpy.management` submodule.  You will get an error if you try to call it from the `arcpy` module.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line which makes no sense and you don't need it:

```
id = max(set(str(for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointlyr, "OBJECTID")))
```

It appears you are trying to store the object ID of the row created by the insert cursor.  If you read the help file on the [insertRow](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm#M1_GUID-DA74F0E0-2D67-472A-84B3-CB594A43750B) method of an insert cursor, insert what it returns into your list.

Comment: The code here gives me the most recent OBJECTID created. The issue remains where the newly created records cannot be selected on the map.